# Sails js - How to obtain and display a specific attribute already populated to a view

Tags: node.js, model-view-controller, sails.js

I'm kind of new in Sails js, and i have a little issue, recently, I learned to populate models, which need to be associated (one to many), and it was successful, the issue was when i need to display on my view a nested attribute of a model, i will show the code, to explain myself.

Here is my first model:

```
module.exports = {

schema: true,
tableName: 'mStore',

attributes: {

    id_store: {
        type: 'integer',
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
    },
    namestore :{
        type: 'string',
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    [...]
    //****WAREHOUSE******
    //RELATION ONE TO MANY WITH WAREHOUSE
    warehouses:{
        collection: 'Warehouse',
        via: 'location'
    },
    [...]

}
```

Here is my second Model:

```
module.exports = {

schema: true,
tableName: 'mWarehouse',

attributes: {

    id_warehouse: {
        type: 'integer',
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
    },
    namewarehouse :{
        type: 'string',
        required: true
    },
    //****STORE******
    //RELATION MANY TO ONE WITH STORE
    location:{
        model: 'Store'
    }
}
```

As you can see, I have Store model which is associated with Warehouse model, a Store can have many Warehouses, I'm doing a CRUD for Warehouse, so i need to display in a view the atributes of Warehouse, for be more specific not just the `id_store`, but others like `namestore` but I dont know how to do it, this is the populate method i use, and the `.ejs` I'm using.

```
Store.find(storeObj).populate('warehouses',warenameObj).exec(function(err,r){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
        else{
            console.log("Populate (Store -> Warehouse) successful!");
        }
});

Warehouse.find(cont).populate('location', storeObj).exec(function(err,r){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
        else{
            console.log("Populate (Warehouse -> Store) successful!");
        }
});
```

And this is the `.ejs`

```
<h1><%= warehouse.namewarehouse %></h1>
<div class="divForms">

    <h3><strong>Is in the store:</strong> <%=warehouse.location.namestore%></h3>
```

It displays the Warehouse attributes like `warehouse.namewarehouse` perfectly, but I really don't know how to display `warehouse.location.namestore` for example.
Help really appreciated!